# changing bar fill colours in ssrs chart

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

[SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993343/ssrs-field-expression-to-change-the-background-color-of-the-cell)

Current I've got 5 bars in my RS chart - in the future there might be 7 bars or 17 bars or 27 bars!

With a couple of bars I can have an expression like this:

```
=iif(Fields!Market.Value = "Spain"
,"Gold"
,iif (Fields!Market.Value = "Denmark"
    , "Gray"
    , iif(Fields!Market.Value = "Italy"
        , "Blue"
        , "Purple"
        )
    )
)
```

If I can't predict how many countries will be included + I'd rather not have to hard code in "Green", "Red" etc how do I change the expression?

I've tried this but it is erroring:

```
=Switch(Mod(Fields!Rank.Value/CDbl(2))=CDbl(0), "Gold", 
   Mod(Fields!Rank.Value/CDbl(3))=CDbl(0), "Gray", 
   Mod(Fields!Rank.Value/CDbl(2))>CDbl(0) "Blue")
```

Above is the totally incorrect syntax: This works:

```
=Switch(CDbl(Fields!Rank.Value Mod 2)=CDbl(0), "Gold", 
   CDbl(Fields!Rank.Value Mod 3)=CDbl(0), "Gray", 
   CDbl(Fields!Rank.Value Mod 2)>CDbl(0), "Blue")
```

Ok - the above runs (not sure how!) but the below is based on help from Dominic Goulet and is really easy to follow and nice and expandable to more colours; this is the solution for 5 colours:

```
=Switch(CDbl(Fields!Rank.Value Mod 5)=CDbl(0), "Gold", 
   CDbl(Fields!Rank.Value Mod 5)=CDbl(1), "Gray", 
   CDbl(Fields!Rank.Value Mod 5)=CDbl(2), "Green", 
   CDbl(Fields!Rank.Value Mod 5)=CDbl(3), "Red", 
   CDbl(Fields!Rank.Value Mod 5)=CDbl(4), "Pink")
```

Comment: Your last switch is not right. 12 will result in "Gold", where it should be "Gray". You should use a (Fields!Rank.Value Mod 3 = 0), (Fields!Rank.Value Mod 3 = 1) and (Fields!Rank.Value Mod 3 = 2) conditions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, instead of using many "IIF"s, you should use "Switch", it's leaner that way.

```
Switch(Fields!Market.Value = "Spain", "Gold",
       Fields!Market.Value = "Denmark", "Gray",
       Fields!Market.Value = "Italy", "Blue")
```

Now if you want a color per coutry, you should defenitely store that in your database and pull it out when you need it. That way, a country will always have the same color on every report you have.

Comment: think I've had a better idea - rank the countries (or whatever dimension is in the report) and add the rank into the data - then see if the number is divisible by two and if so give it one colour - otherwise a second colour.

Comment: That's called "alternating colors". It is a valid technique, mostly used within tables to get alternating row colors.

Comment: i've just added my attempt to the OP ...can you see what is wrong with it: I'm hoping to get 3 alternating colours

Comment: I have similar issue but my problem is I don't know what values I will get... I will get integers but I need to set a color for every integer I get... can you guide me ?

Answer (score 4):

It would be better to create a function. For that, go to Report Properties, choose code and type this example :

```
Public Function Color(ByVal Index as Integer) as String

Select Case Index
Case = 1        
    return "#a6cee3"    
Case = 2        
    return "#1f78b4"    
Case = 3        
    return "#b2df8a"    
Case = 4        
    return "#33a02c"    
Case = 5        
    return "#fb9a99"    
Case = 6        
    return "#e31a1c"    
Case = 7        
    return "#fdbf6f"    
Case = 8        
    return "#ff7f00"    
Case = 9        
    return "#cab2d6"    
Case = 10       
    return "#6a3d9a"    

End Select

End Function
```

On the Fill option from "Series Properties->Pick color-> Color choose fx 
put this code

```
=Code.Color(rownumber(nothing))
```

Each bar will have a color.

For the HEX colors I took from the website : http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=qualitative&scheme=Paired&n=10
It shows the best colors that match with each other, so you don't need to think of that. And you can add as many colors as you want

Comment: This was perfect for me. Thank you for giving such a clear answer.
The updated path is to right-click on a bar in the graph then "Series Properties -> Fill -> Pick Color -> [fx] button".
The last change I did was to change the "Select Case Index" to "Select Case (Index MOD 4)" and change the case values to 0 to 3. This allowed me to have an unlimited number of rows. The colors rotated through those 4 colors.