# How do I keep the legends/colours of SSRS charts consistent?

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

I have been having a couple of issues with my charts in SSRS. Basically, the graphs display the results of a sharepoint survey by counting up the totals of question responses. (For example, the speed rating graph below uses =Count(Fields!Speed_Rating.Value) to get its data. )

The responses to these questions can range from Very Poor to Very good as shown below in the Speed rating graph.

[image]

The problem I am having is that because there has not yet been a Very Poor response to the Professionalism question yet, Very Poor does not appear in the legend/chart. This stops it being consistent with the other charts even though they should be displaying similar data.

Is there a way to ensure that either the colours stay the same for each field across all charts or that all the fields show up in the legend even when there isn't data present for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134829/changing-bar-fill-colours-in-ssrs-chart

Comment: This question is different than that. @BIDeveloper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate as noted above.

You can set the series color property using a switch statement eg

```
=Switch(Fields!Speed_Rating.Value="Very Poor","DarkRed", Fields!Speed_Rating.Value="Poor","Orange",Fields!Speed_Rating.Value="Good", "Green", Fields!Speed_Rating.Value="Very Good","Blue")
```

Comment: I tried this answer, but it doesn't solve the problem. It keeps static colors for each response. The legend appear only for responses these have values > 0, otherwise the corresponding legend key doesn't appear.