# Adding watermark or background image to vs 2013 report

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

How would you go about adding a watermark or background image to a VS2013 rdlc. I was able to add an image to my report data. I then dragged it to my report, and then the repor tablix was placed over the image. This didn't work because the image was obscured by the report tablix. I then put the image over the report tablix, then the table was obscured. I was not able to "Set it as background."
What would be the steps necessary to make a watermark or background image?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993343/ssrs-field-expression-to-change-the-background-color-of-the-cell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right track with setting the image as background.

1. Set the image as the background image for the report body.
2. Set the tablix `BackgroundColor` to `No Color` (transparent)

[image]